# Mesh Intersection 3D

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, computational-geometry

I'm trying to do mesh intersection using brute force approach, checking each triangle from mesh A against mesh B

Right now I'm getting the result image, but with the blue area not there and not account for the intersection.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < tri_mesh_b.vertices.count; i += 3)
    {
        musa::Triangle triB{ tri_mesh_b.vertices[i], tri_mesh_b.vertices[i + 1], tri_mesh_b.vertices[i + 2] };
        
                for (size_t a = 0; a < tri_mesh_a.vertices.count; a += 3)
                {
                    musa::Triangle triA{ tri_mesh_a.vertices[a], tri_mesh_a.vertices[a + 1], tri_mesh_a.vertices[a + 2] };

                    if (triangle_triangle_intersection_check(triB, triA))
                    {
                        mn::buf_push(self->modelIntersection.points, triA.p0);

                        mn::buf_push(self->modelIntersection.points, triA.p1);

                        mn::buf_push(self->modelIntersection.points, triA.p2);


                        musa::Intersection_Segments segments_ = musa::triangle_triangle_intersection(triB, triA);



                        mn::buf_push(self->modelIntersection.points, segments_.segments[0].start);

                        mn::buf_push(self->modelIntersection.points, segments_.segments[0].end);


                        musa::Intersection_Points pts = musa::segment_triangle_intersection(segments_.segments[0], triA);
                        mn::buf_push(self->modelIntersection.points, pts.points[0]);

                        
                    }

        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can you expect to get an answer without a reproducible example nor explanation what particular data structures hold? What are blue triangles - are they triangles that are reported in error or not reported in error?  Besides, brute-force method like yours will kill the performance.  Try "smart" data structures like BVH trees.

Comment: @zkoza I'm using Octrees, but for clarification I'm doing brute force here in stackoverflow. The blue triangles are the ones that are missing using the code above.

Comment: I can't see much in the image... Do the blue triangles intersect with some triangles of the cube, or are they completely inside the cube and hence are not reported? Besides, have you tried visualization with meshlab?

Comment: At a glance, it looks like you're missing the blue faces because you're checking the intersection with the cube faces, not the cube itself.

Comment: @ZeroUltimax Can you tell me the fix please ?

Comment: @zkoza The blue triangles are inside the cube, and hence not reported

Comment: The fix is principally easy. Ray tracing. Shoot a ray from each triangle of mesh B towards a point (or a few points to be sure) that is certainly on  (the surface of) mesh A and count the number of intersections. This will tell you if the starting point is inside mesh A. All  triangles containing such starting points either intersect with mesh A or are inside it completely. Then do the same trick with A and B interchanged. You can use, for example Intel embree library (it also  implements BVH; I'm not sure if also octrees, but believe me, BVHs are really impressive for this sort of jobs) .

Comment: Of course raytracing is OK only if your meshes are already "watertight".

Comment: @zkoza hit test is slightly different you cast just one ray from the triangle A and test intersections with all triangles of B and count those intersections. Parity (even/odd count) will tell if tested A triangle is inside or not. However implementing this is not as easy as it sounds as you need to account for the edge cases where floating accuracy is a problem (directly or near hitting vertex or edge) in 3D is much harder than in 2D where certain condition rules suffice. Maybe remembering all intersection points and counting just distinct ones as changing ray direction bring other problems

Comment: I would go for tetrahedronization of B and test all its triangles instead (however that is also not as easy as just ear clipping).

Comment: @Spektre Hit test is fast, pretty reliable and you can have several target or source points to account for numerical problems with  the triangle edges (rays are "voting", then chose the majority of votes from several rays). Also, sufficiently close intersection points along a ray can be merged into one (compensating "edge effect").  Efficient implementations of RT are widely available.  Dealing with ALL possible numerical errors, even in such a seemingly trivial problem, is a *formidable* task, given that the OP's meshes are essentially arbitrary.

Comment: Looks like your blue are is inside the cube so no intersection with the surface of the cube... isn't it just that?

Comment: @PierreBaret yes